# Running the applets in a web browser

Tags: java, image, applet, embedded-resource

I run an `Applet` on the Applet Viewer of Eclipse and Netbeans IDEs, the applet contain a text and image, it runs fine, it displays the image and the text correctly.

When I run it on the browsers as Firefox 31 and Firefox 33, and Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m, it displays the text, and not the image.

I test the absolute and relative path, but the result was the same.

This image displays the details:

http://s23.postimg.org/qm9huz6sr/10_11_2014_14_45_46.jpg

When I display the java console on the browsers, it doesn't show any problem or exception.

Comment: Where does the applet get the image from? User's file system?

Comment: You did not happen to have any code nor configs?

Comment: Yes, a user file system.
@mico I don't understand your question.

Comment: Don't mind. I did wanted to see some code to know what is the issue. Then I found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847394/java-applet-images-will-not-display-when-run-in-browser Maybe you try using resources from classpath like this guy.

Comment: @mico this is an explain image: 
http://s23.postimg.org/qm9huz6sr/10_11_2014_14_45_46.jpg

Comment: Try trailing dash / in the beginning of path, so "/img/" and so on.

Comment: Should image and imageIcon point to same file, also by type? Or do you have icon files separately? I saw other jpg, other png.

Comment: This is not the problem, because the applet runs correctly in Applet Viewer.

Comment: 1) Never try to load a resource inside the `paint()` method.  2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) Don't ost screenshots of textual information, post the text itself! 4) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).